# Matlab: command to check for active bit in binary numbers?

Tags: matlab, math, binary

This is how I do it with arrays where binaries are stored

```
>> hhh=[1 0 1 0 1 0 0; 0 0 1 0 0 0 0; 1 0 1 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 1 1 0 1]; find(hhh(:,1)==1)

ans =

     1
     3
```

and now I am trying to understand how to do it with binary numbers

```
>> hhhh=[1010100; 0010000; 1010000; 0001101]; find(hhhh(:,1)==1)

ans =

   Empty matrix: 0-by-1
```

where the hack to break up all binaries back into arrays can work (ismember('101010','1') and then prepending with zeros) but I feel there is probably some better alternative so

> **By which command to check whether Nth bit active in binary number?**

*P.s. Harder puzzle: is there a type-agnostic solution that would work with both binaries and DEC?*

Comment: You realize that when you type `1010100` you don't get a binary number, right? You get the decimal number "One million, ten thousand and one hundred".

Comment: How are you storing your binary arrays? That just looks like a `double` array to me

Comment: @Dan just like that so far.

Comment: @hhh well those aren't binary numbers then, they are decimals. I think you should stick with strings: `hhhh=['1010100'; '0010000'; '1010000'; '0001101'];`

Comment: 0001101 can't be a `double` representation anyway. It'd be reduced to 1101.

Comment: Why store "binary numbers" as strings or arrays of logicals, when you could store the very same information as in `'1010100'` in an integer `84`?

Comment: @sebastian ...well this is a puzzle to the larger problem [here](http://pastie.org/8437191). I have sparse structure where active bits are checked from the the indices. This problem is far easier to understand in thinking binaries, in reality the numbers are just indices, apparently in DEC.

Comment: So? Why do you "need" to work with the `dec2bin` output? You could use `bitget` right on the output of `find(mlf)`. Like: `filled = find(mlf); filled_and_bit2 = filled(bitget(filled,2))`

Comment: @sebastian I see! `>> filled = find(mlf); filled_and_bit2 = bitget(filled,1); filled(logical(filled_and_bit2))` Cool :) Thank you!

Comment: Exactly - weird though, that `bitget` returns double, rather than logical...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### String Input

If you have a string input, you can get away with testing for `char` equality:

```
find(hhh(:, 1) == '1')
```

for string arrays (*i.e* `char` matrices), you can extract both outputs of `find` (rows and columns) to be able to determine which active bit corresponds to which string:

```
[r, c] = find(hhh == '1');
```

#### Numeric Input

For numeric inputs, you can use [`bitget`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitget.html) to get the binary representation. From there, it's very similar to the solution for string inputs:

```
B = bsxfun(@bitget, hhh, size(hhh, 1):-1:1);
[r, c] = find(B);
```

Note that `find` searches for non-zero elements, so there's no need to write `find(B == 1)` explicitly.

#### Combined Solution

If the solution for the "harder puzzle" is what you're after, you can determine the type of the input first, and handle it accordingly:

```
if ischar(hhh)
    %// Apply solution to string array
    %//...
else if isnumeric(hhh)
    %// Apply solution to numeric input
    %// ...
else
    %// This type is unsupported
    assert('Matrix is of unsupported type')
end
```

Comment: This works! `hhhh=['1010100'; '0010000'; '1010000'; '0001101']; find(hhhh(:,3)=='1')

ans =

     1
     2
     3`, thank you +1

Comment: @EitanT `[r, c] = find(find(hhh(:, 1) == '1'))`, won't this always just return something like `r == [1,2,3,4...]` and `c=[1,1,1,1...]`?

Comment: Suppose instead of binary numbers, you had something like this `hhhhh=[84;16;80;13];` (same numbers as in binary) so by the above method `hhhhhh=dec2bin(hhhhh);find(hhhhhh(:,3)=='1')` -- would you still use the same method or some other? I thought substracting the 2^N from the number and then checking how many bits changes but this would again require conversion to binary, any smart way to check everything in DEC? Or method to work with both despite the conversion?

Comment: @hhh yes just try `find(hhhhh >= 16)`

Comment: @Dan sorry but that won't do it. Find out all cases where the 5th bit is one/active: it is not `find(hhhhh>=16`, this also finds cases where the 5th bit is zero such as `10000000`.

Comment: @Dan for arrays of strings (assuming each row represents a different binary number), `[r, c] = find(...)` should return the positions of the ones in `c`, and `r` indicates the index of the corresponding row. Does that make more sense to you?

Comment: @EitanT I'm not understanding. Is this the sort of array you mean:`['1010100'; '0010000'; '1010000'; '0001101'];`? Because then the inner find will always be a column of non zero numbers so the outer find will just give and `r` vector of ascending integers and a `c` vector of ones

Comment: @Dan There is only one `find`. I've copy-pasted another "find" by mistake. Thanks for drawing my attention to it :)

Comment: @EitanT np. But since `hhh(:,1)` will always have 1 column, the second output doesn't add anything.

Comment: @Dan When it's a string array, I'm feeding `find` with then entire matrix.

Comment: @EitanT like this?  `>> hhhh=['1010100'; '0010000'; '1010000'; '0001101']; [r,c]=find(hhhh==1)

r =

   Empty matrix: 0-by-1


c =

   Empty matrix: 0-by-1`?

Comment: @EitanT what does "char equality" mean? Some example?

Comment: @hhh it means that you need to write `== '1'` instead of `== 1`. Note the apostrophes `''`.

Comment: I am stuck to the numeric thing, [ERR](http://pastie.org/8437191), I cannot understand the `8:-1:1`.

Comment: @hhh the 8 is just an arbitrary size. It should be `size(hhh, 1)`. This decreasing series simply denotes the positions at which you want to extract the bits (it's decreasing so that the leftmost bit is the most significant one). For example, if your binary numbers have 32 bits, it should be `32:-1:1`. In the general case, it should be `size(hhh, 1):-1:1`, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Repeating my comment in form of an answer:

There's no need to work with the string/array-like representation of the bits in this case.
You can use `bitget` right on the output of `find(mlf)`. Like:

```
filled = find(mlf);
filled_and_bit2 = filled(logical(bitget(filled,2)));
```

Comment: +1 good point, drew more attention also to this in the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19636114/164148).

Answer (score 0):

You should store your binary number as a string matrix:

```
hhhh=['1010100'; '0010000'; '1010000'; '0001101'];
```

Then you can do

```
find(bin2dec(hhhh) >= bin2dec('1000000'))
```

returns:

```
ans =

   1
   3
```

or you could use the less intuitive (but probably faster)

```
find(hhhh(:,1)-'0')  %// Or find(hhhh(:,1)=='1') as EitanT points out
```

to get the same result.

Comment: This `hhhh=['1010100'; '0010000'; '1010000'; '0001101']; find(bin2dec(hhhh) > bin2dec('0010000'))` should return `1 2 3` and not just `1 2`, the larger-than comparison is not checking for one active bit i.e. whether Nth bit is 1...

Comment: @hhh then use `>=` but the string handling versions will be quicker as they don't need to call `bin2dec`

Comment: I cannot yet unedrstand this `find(hhhh(:,1)-'0')`, it seems to return correct results...

Comment: @hhh the char's all have equivalent integer values (ascii values), so `'0' - '0'` is the same as `48 - 48` which is `0`. `'1' - '0'` is not zero so `find` finds it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the question but related -- good point by Sebastian in a comment! So suppose that the binaries are indices. Now instead of playing with dec2bin something like

```
>> hhh=dec2bin(find(mlf));B=bsxfun(@bitget, hhh, 8:-1:1);find(B)
Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.
```

we  can directly address the indices like

```
>> filled = find(mlf); 
filled_and_bit2 = bitget(filled,1); 
filled(logical(filled_and_bit2))

ans =

     1
     7
```

where it finds the binaries with the first active bit.

**Procedure**

> **Data**
>
> ```
> >> mlf=sparse([],[],[],2^31,1);
> mlf(1)=7;
> mlf(4)=10;
> mlf(7)=-1;
> >> mlf
>
> mlf =
>
>                       (1,1)                       7
>                       (4,1)                      10
>                       (7,1)                      -1
>
> >> find(mlf)
>
> ans =
>
>      1
>      4
>      7
> ```
>
> **Interpret the index numbers as binary**
>
> ```
> (1,1) -----> 000001
>
> (4,1) -----> 000100
>
> (7,1) -----> 000111
> ```
>
> **Examples**
>
> > **Output 1:** find cases where 3th bit is active
> >
> > ```
> > 4
> >
> > 7
> > ```
> >
> > **Output:** find cases where 1st bit is active
> >
> > ```
> > 1
> >
> > 7
> > ```
> >
> > **Output:** find cases where 2nd bit is active
> >
> > ```
> > 4
> > ```